# Python(Flask) User Input form

Tags: python, flask, data-science

I'm pretty new to python flask, Just wanted to check my code below, where I'm doing things wrong.

As when I'm running when on URL like (`localhost:5000/submit?name=dial&id=565337`) it's running properly, though it's not running when I'm passing values on the form and producing an error.

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
import Eoc_Summary
import Eoc_Daily
import Eoc_AdSize
import Eoc_Video
import Eoc_Intraction
import EOC_definition
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)

form = '''
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "http://localhost:5000" method="POST">
         <p>Enter Name:</p>
         <p><input type = "text" name = "name" /></p>
         <p>Enter id:</p>
         <p><input type = "text" name = "id" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
'''

@app.route("/")
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return form
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        id = request.form['id']
        return submit(name, id)

@app.route('/submit')
def submit():
    name = request.args.get('name')
    id = request.args.get('id')
    c = Config(name, int(id))

    obj_summary=Eoc_Summary.Summary(c)
    obj_summary.main()
    obj_daily=Eoc_Daily.Daily(c)
    obj_daily.main()
    obj_adSize=Eoc_AdSize.ad_Size(c)
    obj_adSize.main()
    obj_Video=Eoc_Video.Video(c)
    obj_Video.main()
    obj_Intraction=Eoc_Intraction.Intraction(c)
    obj_Intraction.main()
    obj_definition=EOC_definition.definition(c)
    obj_definition.main()
    c.saveAndCloseWriter()
    return 'Report Generated'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Try putting a slash after localhost:5000 like this: localhost:5000/ in the form action

Comment: @TimLee Thanks for your response however still getting error "Method Not Allowed"
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Comment: next to @app.route("/") put methods =['GET','POST] like so: @app.route("/", methods =['GET','POST]) This lets flask know that the get and post methods are coming in.

Comment: Now it's giving internal server error

Comment: Send the post request to /submit by changing the form action address and specifying methods=[‘POST’] in /submit routing. Also, at the end of submit routing, return a redirect by putting  redirect(‘http:/localhost:5000/‘)  you will have to import redirect from flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the methods in your decorator

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
   {...}
```

Also you'll have to add your arguments `name` and `id` to `submit():`

```
@app.route('/submit')
def submit(name, id):
   {...}
```

Finally, import `make_response`

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, make_response
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, its not working giving an error.

Comment: You have to import `make_response` as `from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, make_response`

Comment: You also need to add the arguments for `submit()`. I edited my reply.

Comment: Now its giving this error. " c = Config(name,int(id))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'"

Comment: What value did you input for `id` ?

Comment: it is an integer

Comment: As you now add `name` and `id` in the function `submit` I think you do not need `name = request.args.get('name')` and `id = request.args.get('id')`. Also, you can set `id` as an integer in `index()` like `id = int(request.form['id'])`, then `c = Config(name, id)`

Comment: awesome!! its working fine now. thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, if it works can you please close the question by validating the answer?